# Not able to set cookies secure and HttpOnly properties

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

For whatever reason when I try to set the secure and HttpOnly properties through Javascript, they fail to get set.  Here is the code that is being used:

```
function Selected(StationID,QueryString)
    {
    ClearColours();
    document.getElementById(StationID).className='StationSummary_Container_Selected';
    setCookie('selectedItem',StationID,1);
    setCookie('selectedItemValue',StationID,1);
    setCookie('selectedItemQString',QueryString,1);
    window.location="#" + StationID;
    parent.frames["stationDetail"].location = "StationDetail.aspx?" + QueryString;
    parent.frames["message"].location = "StationMessage.aspx?" + QueryString;
}

function setCookie(NameOfCookie, value, expiredays) {
    var ExpireDate = new Date();
    ExpireDate.setTime(ExpireDate.getTime() + (expiredays * 24 * 3600 * 1000));
    var newCookie = NameOfCookie + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + ExpireDate.toGMTString()) + "; Secure; HttpOnly";
    document.cookie = newCookie;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any tips on this.

Answer (score 0):

The browser does not allow you to read or write `HttpOnly` attribute using JavaScript for security reasons.

The clue is in the name, I guess: *Http**Only***.

You can set these attributes on the server if you need to.